# Javascript sort array of strings containing year using

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to sort an array of seasons by season and year, while removing duplicate seasons. The sort is not enough I guess I need to go by a regex but could not accomplish it

```js
const myStringArray = ["Winter 17", "Summer 13", "Winter 15", "Summer 12", "Winter 17", "Summer 12", "Summer 17"]
     
console.log(_.uniq(myStringArray).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;                                  
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: How do you expect `return b - a` to work when the values are strings, not numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```js
const myStringArray = ["Winter 17", "Summer 13", "Winter 15", "Summer 12", "Winter 17", "Summer 12", "Summer 17"]

console.log(_.uniq(myStringArray).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.split(' ')[1] - a.split(' ')[1] || a.localeCompare(b);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works like a sharm, tkx

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the year, then take the index of an created array that sets the order of season. To make the array unique, simply use a new Set

```js
const myStringArray = [...new Set(["Winter 17", "Summer 13", "Winter 15", "Summer 12", "Winter 17", "Summer 12", "Summer 17"])];
const order = ['Winter', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Spring'];

myStringArray.sort((a, b) => {
  let s = b.split(/\s/);
  let s1 = a.split(/\s/);
  return Number(s1[1]) - Number(s[1]) || order.indexOf(s[0]) * -1;
});

console.log(myStringArray);
```

Comment: Why convert an array to a set, then convert the set back to an array?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how else to sort a set - do you?

Comment: No, that makes no sense. Why are you creating the set in the first place, instead of just `const myStringArray = ["Winter 17", "Summer 13", "Winter 15", "Summer 12", "Winter 17", "Summer 12", "Summer 17"];`

Comment: @Barmar because op asks explicitly for uniqueness. Else The array isn’t unique

Comment: @Barmar ah that’s what you mean... I just prefer using built ins instead of libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you your strings will always be in the format `<Season YY>` and digits will only appear once, you can use a quick and simple regex to sort desc:

```js
const myStringArray = ["Winter 17", "Summer 13", "Winter 15", "Summer 12", "Winter 17", "Summer 12", "Summer 17"]
     
console.log(_.uniq(myStringArray).sort(function(a, b) {
    return +b.match(/\d+/)[0] - +a.match(/\d+/)[0];                                  
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```